# Selecting multiple counts with left outer join

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've got 3 tables: `Product`, `Shares`, `Likes` which are connected by `ProductID`. What I want to do is to select all products and `COUNT(shares)` and `COUNT(likes)` of these products in one query.

First of all is it possible to do with just one query? If possible how can i do it? And most importantly should I select all products and display then when users hover on make an Ajax call and get like and share data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use some "group by", guys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT
    p.id AS 'product id',
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT s.id), 0) AS 'total shares',
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT l.id), 0) AS 'total likes'
FROM
    products p
    LEFT JOIN shares s ON s.product_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

`IFNULL` will treat cases when there are no shares or likes; `DISTINCT` should be there because otherwise one share will be counted multiple times when joined with likes (and vice versa).

Comment: it works with errors, it shows if there are likes or not, not the number for some reason.

Comment: i deleted the distinct part because what i wanted to do was to get all the products and number of shares and likes from other tables. when i do distinct it works as if checked its liked or not

Comment: if i don't use district it just multiples the tables if i use it then all i get is if a products is liked or not, not the actual number

Comment: Do you put the appropriate id's there? DISTINCT should count id's of shares (s.id) and likes (l.id), not products (not s.product_id and l.product_id).

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do it on one query. Off the top of my head something like

```
SELECT 
   product_id,
   COUNT(likes.product_id) as likes, 
   COUNT(SELECT share_id FROM shares WHERE product_id = p.product_id) as shares
FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN likes USING(product_id)
```

Do watch performance though. Make sure you have your indexes etc

Comment: This will return 1 "like" for a product that has not been liked.  You need to use `COUNT(likes.product_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: shouldn't there also be count in subquery?

Comment: @sashkello Yes but your query is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    p.ProductID,
    COUNT(s.ProductID) AS SharesCount,
    COUNT(l.ProductID) AS LikesCount
FROM
    Products p LEFT JOIN Shares s 
        ON P.ProductID = s.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN likes l 
        ON P.ProductID = l.ProductID

GROUP BY p.ProductID
```